# Class 'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel

File: Composer.json ---------------------------------------

```
 {
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "type": "project",
        "require": {
            "php": ">=7.0.0",
            "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.0",
            "creativeorange/gravatar": "~1.0",
            "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
            "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
            "google/recaptcha": "^1.1",
            "intervention/image": "^2.4",
            "jaybizzle/laravel-crawler-detect": "1.*",
            "jeremykenedy/laravel-exception-notifier": "^1.1",
            "jeremykenedy/laravel-https": "^1.1",
            "jeremykenedy/laravel-logger": "^1.0.1",
            "jeremykenedy/laravel-roles": "^1.1",
            "jeremykenedy/laravel2step": "^1.0.2",
            "jeremykenedy/uuid": "^3.1",
            "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
            "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
            "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
            "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5",
            "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.0",
            "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^0.10.4",
            "socialiteproviders/37signals": "^3.0",
            "socialiteproviders/generators": "^2.0",
            "socialiteproviders/instagram": "^3.0",
            "socialiteproviders/twitch": "^3.0",
            "socialiteproviders/youtube": "^3.0"
        },
    }
```

//File app.php ----------------------------------------

```
 'providers' => [
        SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
        SocialiteProviders\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider::class,
  ],
  'aliases' => [
        'Socialite'    => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
  ]
```

I don't know why it's not founded
root link: https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Manager

Answer (score 6):

This issue is common when composer autoload gets jammed up. The docs say running

`composer dump-autoload` or `php artisan clear-compiled` will fix this but it sometimes does not.

The way to fix this is is to delete the file `/bootstrap/cache/packages.php` and `/bootstrap/cache/services.php` then run `composer update`.

Answer (score 4):

Remove these lines from the `config/app.php`:

```
SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
SocialiteProviders\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider::class,
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Then run these commands:

```
composer install
composer du
```

And then put all three lines back to the `config/app.php`

Comment: thank Alexey, when i run command composer install It's have error:

Comment: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://original.packagist.jp/p/doctrine/dbal%2417ae46d6beb8d0b5cfd7df33d21dbd21443feeaf54bdc9d841ac03de5ab99c
  1d.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.