# Laravel: Class 'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I am getting the following error when I trying to use Socialite with Laravel and extending it with SocialiteProviders. I have tried other solutions but nothing seems to get rid of this error. Does anyone have any suggestions??? Thanks.

ERROR: Class 'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider' not found

File: Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "~4.7.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.3",
        "beyondcode/laravel-mailbox": "^1.2",
        "browner12/helpers": "^2.1",
        "chumper/zipper": "^1.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-sftp": "^1.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
        "socialiteproviders/facebook": "^1.0",
        "socialiteproviders/generators": "^4.5",
        "socialiteproviders/github": "dev-master",
        "socialiteproviders/google": "^3.0",
        "socialiteproviders/instagram": "^3.0",
        "socialiteproviders/linkedin": "^3.1",
        "socialiteproviders/manager": "^3.4",
        "socialiteproviders/twitter": "^3.0",
        "socialiteproviders/vkontakte": "^4.0",
        "socialiteproviders/youtube": "^3.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.40",
        "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^4.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.*",
        "zanysoft/laravel-zip": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
        "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "5.8.x-dev",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.8.0",
        "infyomlabs/adminlte-templates": "5.8.x-dev",
        "infyomlabs/swagger-generator": "dev-master",
        "appointer/swaggervel": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

File app.php

```
    'providers' => [
        \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
    ],

    'aliases' => [
        'Socialite' => Illuminate\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
    ],
```

File: EventServiceProvider.php

```
    protected $listen = [
        \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
            // add your listeners (aka providers) here
            'SocialiteProviders\\Facebook\\FacebookExtendSocialite@handle',
            'SocialiteProviders\\GitHub\\GitHubExtendSocialite@handle',
            'SocialiteProviders\\Google\\GoogleExtendSocialite@handle',
            'SocialiteProviders\\Instagram\\InstagramExtendSocialite@handle',
            'SocialiteProviders\\LinkedIn\\LinkedInExtendSocialite@handle',
            'SocialiteProviders\\PayPal\\PayPalExtendSocialite@handle',
            'SocialiteProviders\\Twitter\\TwitterExtendSocialite@handle',
            'SocialiteProviders\\VKontakte\\VKontakteExtendSocialite@handle',
            'SocialiteProviders\\YouTube\\YouTubeExtendSocialite@handle',
        ],
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];
```

File: AuthController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    ...
```

Comment: It might be cause of `composer` - `dump-autoload` might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48377009/4705339

Comment: @senty tried that already still getting the error.

Comment: @senty When I run composer dump-autoload I get this error again at the bottom: In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                                
  Class 'SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Does `SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider` actually exist?

Comment: @senty Do you know the path to it when installed by composer?

Comment: It's inside vendor directory

Comment: @senty NOPE can't see a "SocialiteProviders" there anywhere there in the top level.

Comment: @senty Do you know if you have to install Manager separately of the providers using composer? I'm installing each like this ``` composer require socialiteproviders/google
Using version ^3.0 for socialiteproviders/google
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed```

Comment: Hmm..... "Killed" could be the problem when running composer! How do I fix that...

Answer (score 1):

Newbie issue.... Composer self "Killed". Fixed the issue by adding swap memory before running composer.

UPDATED to include the command I used to add swap and fix the problem.

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Comment: How did you add more swap memory?

Comment: @DavidKanenwisher followed the instructions on this site the user was experiencing a similar problem: [https://trinitytuts.com/tips/composer-killed-terminal-updating/]
`/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1`

Comment: It looks like the brackets around the link to trinitytuts link is causing trouble when it's clicked.

Comment: @DavidKanenwisher  http://trinitytuts.com/tips/composer-killed-terminal-updating/  That should work better. :)